# How to test UITableView by XCUITest

Tags: xcode, automated-tests, swift2

there.

I'm writing test code by XCUITest.
I want to test UITableView.
But I couldn't test now on UITableView.
I don't know why cell tap has no response.

I have written the following code.

```
let tablesQuery = app.tables
    app.tables.cells.staticTexts["山手線"].tap()
    tablesQuery.staticTexts["山手線"].tap()
    tablesQuery.staticTexts["山手線"].tap()

    tablesQuery.staticTexts["渋谷"].tap()
    tablesQuery.staticTexts["大崎"].tap()
    tablesQuery.staticTexts["山手線"].tap()
```

The view which was tested is the following capture.

[image]
[image]

And my test code put out the following error.
[image]

This page has UITableView.
I don't know why cell tap has no response.

What is this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved by myself.
I have setted accessibility something.

```
        self.workview.isAccessibilityElement = true
    self.workview.accessibilityLabel = "workview"
```

after I comment out the above code,I could test.

Thank you!